# How to parse nested json object in java? (Object inside json Object)

Tags: java, json, spring

I have the JSON structure as similar to below. I want to read the nested value "criteria" object from this JSON, How to parse this JSON in java.

```
{
   "criteria":{
      "LogicalOperator":"copy",
      "Groups":[
         {
            "LogicalOperator":"AND",
            "condition":[
               {
                  "column":"name",
                  "Operator":"CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Shiva"
               },
               {
                  "column":"name",
                  "Operator":"NOT CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Bhangari"
               },
               {
                  "column":"name",
                  "Operator":"EQUAL",
                  "Value":"Shiva"
               },
               {
                  "column":"name",
                  "Operator":"NOT EQUAL",
                  "Value":"Shivanand"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "LogicalOperator":"OR",
            "condition":[
               {
                  "column":"city",
                  "Operator":"CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Ben"
               },
               {
                  "column":"city",
                  "Operator":"NOT CONTAINS",
                  "Value":"Hyd"
               },
               {
                  "column":"city",
                  "Operator":"EQUAL",
                  "Value":"Bengaluru"
               },
               {
                  "column":"city",
                  "Operator":"NOT EQUAL",
                  "Value":"Jaipur",
                  
                  "criteria":{
                     "LogicalOperator":"AND",
                     "Groups":[
                        {
                           "LogicalOperator":"AND",
                           "condition":[
                              {
                                 "column":"name",
                                 "Operator":"CONTAINS",
                                 "Value":"Shiva"
                              },
                              {
                                 "column":"name",
                                 "Operator":"NOT CONTAINS",
                                 "Value":"Bhangari"
                              },
                              {
                                 "column":"name",
                                 "Operator":"EQUAL",
                                 "Value":"Shiva"
                              },
                              {
                                 "column":"name",
                                 "Operator":"NOT EQUAL",
                                 "Value":"Shivanand"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I am able to read first object "Criteria", but how to do operations on nested objcts("You can see in the json nested "criteria" object).

Java code below which I have tried,

```
//method to retrieve the json file 
public static void getKey(JSONObject json, String key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Boolean exists = json.has(key);
        Iterator<?> keys;
        String nextKeys;

        if (!exists) {

            keys = json.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {

                nextKeys = (String) keys.next();
                try {
                    if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONObject) {
                        if (exists == false) {
                            getKey(json.getJSONObject(nextKeys), key);
                        }

                    } else if (json.get(nextKeys) instanceof JSONArray) {
                        String outerLo = String.valueOf(json.get("LogicalOperator"));
                        System.out.println(outerLo);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(nextKeys);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            String jsonArrStr = jsonArray.get(i).toString();

                            JSONObject innerJson = new JSONObject(jsonArrStr);
                            String lo = String.valueOf(innerJson.get("LogicalOperator"));
                            JSONArray result = innerJson.getJSONArray("condition");
                            // JSONArray grpRes = innerJson.getJSONArray("Groups");
                            // System.out.println(grpRes);
                            // List of objects
                            List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();

                            // Dummy data for testing
                            List<CustomerPojo> list = getCustomerData();

                            System.out.println(lo);
                            for (int j = 0; j < result.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject result1 = result.getJSONObject(j);

                                // Filtering if the operator= "contains for AND Logical Operator
                                if (lo.equals("AND")) {
                                    conditionAND(objList, list, result1);
                                } else if (lo.equals("OR")) {
                                    conditionOR(objList, list, result1);
                                }

                            }

                        // removing duplicate entries from OR Condition
                            if (lo.equals("OR")) {
                                filteringOrConditon(objList);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do not parse the Json like that, use Jackson instead. If you're using Spring, you already have the needed dependencies for doing it. Also, you will benefit of clean POJOs and automatic validation from Spring in case someone sends you an invalid json.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ Any reference ? So that I can get some clear idea.

Comment: You can start [from here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)